# Differential of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand how to find the derivative, but how should I find the differential of a complex function?

Answer (score 3):

The differential is $$\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y$$ just as in two-variable real calculus. Using the Wirtinger derivatives $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Big)$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Big),$$ and the one-forms $\mathrm{d}z = \mathrm{d}x + i \mathrm{d}y$ and $\mathrm{d}\overline{z} = \mathrm{d}x - i \mathrm{d}y$, you can rewrite this as $$\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \mathrm{d}z + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} \mathrm{d}\overline{z}.$$